# Can I modify an xml file only from command line?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

There is an auto-generated xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <widget id="some ID" modes="max">
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <name>StackOverflow</name>
  <feature name="some feature"/>
```

I would like to achieve following:

1. subtitute `modes` with `"full"`
2. subtitute `name` with `${name}`
3. remove `<feature>`
4. add `<content src="index.html"/>` in between `<icon>` and `<name>`

Can this be done?

[adding more background]

It is an website mostly made of node.js.  This shell command will be run on server-side Javascript and will be executed using `child_process.exec()`.

Comment: You tagged `sed` even though it's an external tool and not pure bash. How about using an external tool meant for this like `xmlstarlet`?

Comment: this code needs to be run on Ubuntu server, and I am not sure `xmlstarlet` is installed there.  I think `sed` is initially available from scartch.

Comment: @RNA: You can confirm the availability by doing `which xmlstarlet`

Comment: @RNA: even some tool is not available on your server (and you don't have root access on that server) you can still install Ubuntu on your laptop and compile `xmlstarlet` (or any other application) locally on your laptop then `scp` the executable. However, it could be likely that the server has some relevant XML program installed.

Comment: `bash` is mostly (like any other Unix shell) a tool to start other programs. So you should actually find what *available* programs are installed on your remote server. `sed` (which is an *external* program) might do the job at least if `${name}`  don't contain naughty characters like `'`, `"`, `<`, `>`; and perhaps you might politely ask the sysadmin of the remote server to install additional Ubuntu packages.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this script is going to run inside of Javascript.  So it is not like I can install this and that, is it?

Comment: How exactly do you start that script from Javascript? And what implementation of Javascript do you use (Node.js perhaps?)?? You need to **edit your question** to give a *lot* more details.

Comment: It is a website built with Meteor.  I am trying to execute bash shell command by using `child_process.exec()` https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: the xml in the question is generated by command line interface of some other app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `awk` is also an standard GNU tool, I think it might meet your requirement.
It's an very straightforward script you can adopt.

```
awk '
  /modes/{gsub(/modes=".*"/,"modes=\"full\"") }
  /<icon/{$0=$0"\n  <content src=\"index.html\"/>"}
  /<name>/{gsub(/>.*</,">$name<")}
  !/feature/{print}
' Your_XML_file
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <widget id="some ID" modes="full">
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <name>$name</name>
```

And here's the brief explain I would give,

1. find modes and  in your xml file, and modify as you desire
2. find "< icon", and insert  below it.
3. remove the line contain feature